# Tag to exclude a part of a file when I do a commit?

Tags: c#, svn, app-config

We are working with two different teams on the same project. In a configuration file App.config, we have two connections string with our connection settings to connect to our database and the second team has another database with a different connection string. I have to comment the second connection string and uncomment the first. I have to check always this file if the connection string is correct (if the another team has not commited this file). It's a little bit boring..

This configuration file contains some other configurations keys that we use in common. My goal is to set (on the config file with a  or somewhat) to tell to SVN to not include this part of file when I made a commit.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Partial file commits aren't possible in any version tracking system I've ever seen.  You can however take a look at something like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx) if you're using VS2010.

Comment: But I have: TortoiseHg let you choose which parts of a file to commit (on the hunk selection tab). Git also has this function, but I don't recall how it's spelled there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `configSource` attribute to have ASP.NET read the config from an external file instead of the main config file. That way you can have one dirty and ignore-on-commit file containing the connection strings, and still be able to commit the main config file when changes are needed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that everyone in your teams backup the configuration file, and have someone rename the file in SVN to something like `template.[original-name]` and commit that.

Then, have everybody restore their own configuration file and put in into the `svn:ignore` Subversion property of the directory containing the file, and commit that directory to have the `svn:ignore` in version control for everyone and have them update their working copies after that.

This way, each team member can have a different configuration.

Configuration and user/system specific files should not be in version control.

See also http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html.

**EDIT:** To actually answer your question, [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264607/david) is right, partial file commits are not possible (and usually would not make sense either). It is not the intended workflow of Subversion.